# SQL Server 2008 replication 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I'm going to do SQL Server replication. I can't add publishers. It display as below.

> There are no publications to which you can subscribe, either because
>   this server has no publications or because you do not have sufficient
>   privileges to access the publications.

Please help me to solve this issues. Thank you

Comment: So, does `the server have publications` and do you have `sufficient privileges`?

Comment: "server have publications" what this means?.How can i add this? .yes,privileges is ok..

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152567.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the error you are seeing?

[image]

This occurs when trying to create a subscription without having any publications available on the publisher you selected in the dropdown box.

You can create a publication using the New Publication Wizard. Just right click on the Local Publications folder in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for reply.That is the issue.But in replication folder,there are no folder called "Local Publications".It only includes "local  subcription" folder only.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The express edition cannot run as a publisher or distributor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for replication
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165700(SQL.90).aspx
as it can't be distributor/publisher

Answer (score 0):

Great answer - thought as much. I will now move on to install SQL 2008 (it comes with replication anyway). My expectation from the microsoft link here was that I would get an addOn replication feature as a download - but its not (just more info). Thanks anyway: chagbert.